# ¿ Como quitar hora a fecha en Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo esta fecha1 01/02/2021 09:19:09.0 en una columna y esta fecha2 09/02/2021 en otra columna. Necesito quitar la hora de fecha1, para compararlas y guardar la diferencia de días en otra columna. Gracias!!

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes añadir código con lo que has intentado y un ejemplo de tu dataframe?

Comment: difference = (df_usuarios['fecha_inicio'].dt-df_usuarios['fecha_activo'].dt).days

Comment: orden nombre fecha_inicio fecha_activo
11          juan 09/02/2021 01/02/2021 09:19:09.0
12        valeria 10/02/2021 01/02/2021 09:19:09.1
13        diego 11/02/2021 01/02/2021 09:19:09.2
14        pedro 12/02/2021 04/02/2021 09:19:09.3
15            luis 13/02/2021 01/02/2021 09:19:09.4
16       francisco 14/02/2021 10/02/2021 09:19:09.5
17        leticia 15/02/2021 01/02/2021 09:19:09.6
18        diego 16/02/2021 01/02/2021 09:19:09.7
19       susana 17/02/2021 04/02/2021 09:19:09.8

Comment: Agregado en la pregunta, aquí en los comentarios no se ve bien

Answer (score 1):

Para quitar la hora en **"fecha1"** donde el formato es:

> 01/02/2021 09:19:09.0

Se puede hacer lo siguiente suponiendo que el nombre de la columna que contiene fecha y hora se llame **'fecha activo'**

## Para dejar solo la fecha

```
df['fecha_activo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha_activo']).dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opcón de solución podría ser:

```
# Primero se deja solo la fecha:
df['fecha_activo'] = df['fecha_activo'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
# Se convierte a datetime
df['fecha_activo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha_activo'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['fecha_inicio'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha_inicio'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
diferencia = df['fecha_inicio'] - df['fecha_activo']
```